# Keeping RData loaded on Raspberry Pi or Ubuntu

Tags: r, linux, apache, raspberry-pi

I'm running an apache server on a Raspberry Pi with a predictor that uses R.

The problem is that R has to load some tables from RData files (and some libraries) and it takes a long time (+/- 6 seconds).

Is there a way to keep this data loaded so only the method make_prediction(args) has to run?

Thanks!

Comment: RData is already pretty efficient serialization.  It will be hard to beat that. The optional R image save is using the same format.

Comment: That you for your answer. So there is no way to keep the RData loaded on the apache server / raspberry pi?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  It is a file. You can save it whereever you want.  Upon startup, the process loads it.  If the file is large, and the disk is slow, then that takes a moment.  There really is not anything more to it.

Comment: Aha, maybe my problem description is not clear enough. I will try to make it clearer. I mean that the php script calls a batch command "Rscript my-r-script.r args" which returns a value. That R script first has to load in some RData. I would like that data to be already loaded when the server calls the R script.

Comment: Come on now.  This is the first time you mention PHP in the context. _Obviously_ you want the data in the server so recast your deployment so that R is loaded _in the webserver / becomes the webserver_.

Comment: Allright. I will look into this. Thank you.